# R getURL error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: r, ssl, geturl

I am trying to run these lines in R

```
theurl <- paste("https://www.census.gov/population/international/data/idb/region.php?N=%20Results%20&T=10&A=separate&RT=0&Y=2016&R=-1&C=BR")
tabs <- getURL(theurl,  followlocation=TRUE)
```

And after it, I receive the error below,

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>     error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

It is the first time I'm seeing this error, few months ago I was running these two lines with out any errors. Side note, I'm running R on windows. Can someone help me with solving this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What package does `getURL` come from?

Comment: Upgrade openssl as per the dupe. If that still doesn't work try here again.

Comment: I did upgrade openssl and even tried to reinstall it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Still works for me. Please **edit the question** and add your Windows version, and the version number of R and all relevant R packages. You should probably make sure they are all up to date too.

Comment: i can reproduce the error on windows 10, R 3.6.2, RCurl 1.98-1.1. However, if i open the url in the browser i get `Sorry, the page you requested has either been moved or is no longer available on this server.`. What kind of content are you expecting? Are you requesting the same site @Roger-123?

Comment: The issue has be around for years. https://community.rstudio.com/t/sslv3-alert-handshake-failure/16944 | https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/obiba-users/REr-Czhldbg